# How to find the source code of the default signal handler function?

Tags: c, linux, signals, open-source, signal-handling

I wanted to see the source code of the default handler of SIGABRT in Linux C, But I couldn't find it. Would you please mind help to find it?

Comment: in Linux C? You mean Linux kernel signals handler?

Comment: There isn't a default signal handler at the user-level for SIGABRT (or any other signal, come to that).  The default behaviour for SIGABRT is to terminate with a core dump; that is all handled by the kernel, not by user-level code.

Answer (score 1):

http://lxr.free-electrons.com is a great way to read the linux kernel's source.

Doing a quick search for `SIGABRT` shows that it is used only by the [SIG_KERNEL_COREDUMP_MASK](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/signal.h#L416) macro. This macro is in turn used exclusively by [sig_kernel_coredump](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/signal.h#L427).

Tracing the usage of this macro leads us to the place where the signal handlers are executed in [kernel/signal.c:2301](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c#L2301).

This corresponds to what the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) tell us, i.e. the default action for SIGABRT is to terminate the process and dump the program core memory.